# Show that $\Phi(T)=T\circ T$ is continuous on $\mathcal L(V)$

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $(V,|\cdot |)$ a $\mathbb R-$normed vector-space. Let $X:=\mathcal L(V)$ endowed with the norm $$\|T\|_X:=\sup_{|v|\leq 1}\frac{|T(v)|}{|v|},$$
for all $T\in X$. I want to prove that $\Phi:X\to X$ defined by $\Phi(T)=T\circ T$ is continuous on $X$.

**Attempts**

Les $S\in X$. Let $\varepsilon >0$. Then for $T\in X$ and $v\in V$, \begin{align*}
(\Phi(T)-\Phi(S))(v)&=TTv-SSv\\
&=T(Tv-Sv)+TSv-SSv\\
&=T(Tv-Sv)+Tsv-STv-S(Tv-Sv)
\end{align*}

but I can't find a $\delta >0$ s.t. $\|T-S\|_X<\delta \implies \|\Phi(T)-\Phi(S)\|_X<\varepsilon $

Comment: Why do you think that $\Phi(T)\in X$ whenever $T\in X$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use the consequence
$$
|Tx| \le \|T\|_X \, |x| .
$$

Your computation continues:
\begin{align}
|TTv-SSv| &= |T(Tv-Sv)+TSv-SSv|
\\ &\le |T(Tv-Sv)| + |TSv-SSv|
\\ & \le \|T\|_X\;|Tv-Sv| + \|T-S\|_X\;|Sv|
\\ & \le \|T\|_X\;\|T-S\|_X |v| + \|T-S\|_X\;\|S\|_X\;|v|
\\ & = \|T-S\|_X \big(\|S\|_X+\|T\|_X\big)|v|
\end{align}
so
$$
\|SS - TT\|_X \le \|T-S\|_X \big(\|S\|_X+\|T\|_X\big)
$$
This is what we need.
Now we cannot prove that $\Phi$ is **uniformly continuous**, so we proceed as follows:  Say we want to prove $\Phi$ is continuous at the point $S \in \mathcal L(X)$.  So $S$ is a fixed operator (so $\delta$ is allowed to depend on $S$). Given
$\varepsilon > 0$, let
$$
\delta = \min\left\{1,\frac{\varepsilon}{2\|S\|_X+1}\right\} .
$$
Now let $T \in \mathcal L(X)$ satisfy $\|T-S\|_X \le \delta$.
We have
$\|T\|_X \le \|S\|_X+1$ and then
$$
\|SS - TT\|_X \le \|T-S\|_X \big(\|S\|_X+\|T\|_X\big) \le
\frac{\varepsilon}{2\|S\|_X+1}\;(\|S\|_X+\|S\|_X+1) = \varepsilon .
$$

Answer (score 0):

Look at the usual proof that $f(x)=x^2$ is continuous on $\Bbb{R}$. Also, there's no need to introduce $v\in V$; all you need to know is the operator norm has the nice property $\|T\circ S\|\leq \|T\|\cdot \|S\|$ (I think it's called sub-multiplicative?)

Or, consider the map $\Psi:X\times X\to X$, $\Psi(T,S)=T\circ S$. Due to the above property of operator norms, $\Psi$ is a bounded bilinear map, and thus is continuous. The map $\Phi$ is the composition of $\Psi$ with the diagonal map $T\mapsto (T,T)$.